# Constructing an object without passing at least empty curly brackets produces "(destructured parameter) is undefined" type error

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to write a class with optional named arguments.

```
class MyClass {
      constructor({a=2, b=4, c=3}){
          console.log(b);
      }
    }
```

If I create the object like this

```
let obj = new MyClass({});
```

then all is good.

However, if I create the object like this

```
let obj = new MyClass();
```

I get an error. Is it possible to make it accept empty parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the whole argument also default to the empty object (in addition to the destructured properties defaulting to particular values).

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor({ a=2, b=4, c=3 } = {}){
      console.log(b);
  }
}
let obj = new MyClass();
```